# T/F: $\vdash _{NDFOL}\forall x(B \to A) \to(\exists x B \to A)$

Tags: logic

I need to decide whether the above holds or not.

I know that $\vdash _{HFOL}\forall x(B \to A) \to(\exists x B \to A)$, and if $T=\emptyset$, $T\vdash _{HFOL}\varphi$ then $T\vdash _{NDFOL} \varphi$.
Is it enought to say that $\vdash _{NDFOL}\forall x(B \to A) \to(\exists x B \to A)$?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't hold in general. You need a restriction that $x$ can't occur free in $A$.

Comment: Well, the question says nothing about that. I wonder if that was omitted for a reason....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $H$ indicates a classical Hilbert-style proof system and $ND$ indicates a natural deduction system, then since both systems are sound and complete for $FOL$ it is trivial that if $\vdash_H \varphi$ then $\vdash_{ND} \varphi$, assuming you can appeal to the known meta-results.

But a direct $ND$ proof is very easy anyway, assuming as we must that $x$ doesn't occur free in $A$. For a Fitch-style proof (easily re-arranged into Gentzen-style)

> $\quad|\quad\forall x(B(x) \to A)$
>
> $\quad|\quad|\quad \exists xB(x)$
>
> $\quad|\quad|\quad | \quad B(a)$
>
> $\quad|\quad|\quad | \quad (B(a) \to A)$
>
> $\quad|\quad|\quad | \quad A$
>
> $\quad|\quad|\quad A$
>
> $\quad|\quad (\exists xB(x) \to A)$
>
> $\quad \forall x(B(x) \to A) \to (\exists xB(x) \to A)$.

Exercise: annotate the proof, and explain at which step we rely on the fact that $x$ doesn't occur free in $A$.